# Related entities not loaded in Codeception functional tests

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, functional-testing, codeception

I'm using Codeception to test a Symfony 3.4 project with Doctrine2 module enabled.

The problem is that I can't access related entities on an entity I receive by calling `grabEntityFromRepository()` function. So if I do:

```
$person = $I->grabEntityFromRepository('AppBundle:Person', ['id' => 1]);
$address = $person->getAddress(); // Address is a one to one related entity to person
```

The `$address` variable is NULL.

Is this an expected behaviour or can it be tweaked in the configuration somewhere?

Comment: More details please !

Comment: any specific details you need? Instead of $address being NULL I would expect it to be a fully loaded Address entity.

Comment: Full code and  $person value